# Lisp recursive function missing base case on first call

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I started programming with lisp yesterday so please excuse if I am making some really newbie mistake. I am trying to create a function which calculates the bell numbers using the bell triangle and my recursive triangle function is not working properly. I am also sure if I got my recursive triangle function working that my recursive bell function is somehow also broken.

When I test my triangle function I get the output:

```
(defun bell(l n)
    (if(< n 1)(list 1))
    (if (= n 1)(last l))
    (bell (triangle (reverse l) (last l) (list-length l)) (- n 1))
)
(defun triangle(pL nL i)
    (if(<= i 0)
        (write "equals zero!")
        (reverse nL)
    )
    (triangle pL (append (list (+ (nth i pL) (nth i nL))) nL) (- i 1))  
)
(write (triangle '(1) '(1) 0))


=>


"equals zero!""equals zero!"
*** - NTH: -1 is not a non-negative integer
```

For some reason, it is printing my debug code twice even though the function should be meeting my base case on the first call.

Comment: I rolled back the edit to the title because while OP **is** trying to create a triangle, OP has also identified the real issue here:  the function *isn't* terminating at the expected base case, and that's because of the grouping of the **if**s.  While a solution to the triangle might help OP, the question really is focused on why, for instance, `(defun foo (n) (if (= n 0) 35) 42)` will *always* return 42, even if n is 0.  It's because the code ignores the result of the **if**.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I get your point. The OP is not asking about how to solve the triangle but why he is having that error. Anyway, I thought the post could be more helpful and easily found with a more appropriate title, since the current one does not even represent the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For some reason, it is printing my debug code twice even though the function should be meeting my base case on the first call.

It is printed twice because `if` is not doing what you think it does. The first if test is true, therefore *equals zero!* is printed. After that, a recursive call to triangle function is invoked. The test is again true (-1 <= 0), so *equals zero!* is again printed. Finally, you get an error because `nthcdr` function is called with -1. I strongly recommend you a good lisp debugger. The one from Lispworks is pretty good.

I honestly don't get the logic of what you were trying to achieve with your code. so I wrote mine:

```
(defun generate-level (l &optional (result))
  "given a list l that represents a triangle level, it generates the next level"
  (if (null l) result
    (if (null result)
        (generate-level l (list (car (last l))))
      (generate-level (cdr l) (append result 
                                      (list (+ (car l) 
                                               (car (last result)))))))))


(defun bell (levels &optional (l))
  "generate a bell triangle with the number of labels given by the first parameter"
  (unless (zerop levels)
        (let ((to-print (if (null l) (list 1) (generate-level l))))
          (print to-print)
          (bell (1- levels) to-print))))
```

Things to understand the implementation:

1. `&optional (parameter)`: this parameter is optional and nil by default.
2. `append` concatenates two lists. I'm using it to insert in the back of the list.
3. `let ((to-print x))` creates a new variable binding (local variable) called `to-print` and initialized to `x`.
4. I almost forgot to mention how `if` works in common lisp:
   `(if (= x 1) y z)` means if `x` is equal to 1 then return `y`, otherwise `z`.

Now if you call the function to create a Bell triangle of 7 levels:

```
CL-USER 9 > (bell 7)

(1) 
(1 2) 
(2 3 5) 
(5 7 10 15) 
(15 20 27 37 52) 
(52 67 87 114 151 203) 
(203 255 322 409 523 674 877) 
NIL
```

It would be nicer to print it with the appropiate padding, like this:

```
                    1
                 1     2
              2     3     5
           5     7    10    15
       15    20    27    37    52
    52    67    87   114   151   203
203   255   322   409   523   674   877
```

but I left that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: A few minor comments on the code: You seem to have an unnecessary `AND` in `BELL`. You should also use `UNLESS` instead of `(WHEN (NOT ...))`, and the `(IF (NULL L) ...)` could be moved inside the `LET`-binding so you don't need to repeat code. Maybe also use `COND` instead of nested `IF`s in `GENERATE-LEVEL`.

Comment: @jkiiski Thanks! I haven't coded in Lisp for some time and I'm rusty.

Comment: @FrankS101 Thank you for the in-depth explanation and the solution. I eventually figured out the way the if conditional works. Its one of my first jumps from imperative to functional programming so I was floundering a bit. I just needed the nth bell number instead of the entire triangle and this was the least complicated way to achieve that so I chose this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Your **if**s don't have any effect.  They're evaluated, and produce results, but then you discard them.  Just like

```
(defun abc ()
  'a
  'b
  'c)
```

would evaluate **'a** and **'b** to produce the symbols **a** and **b**, and then would evaluate **'c** to produce the symbol **c**, which would then be returned.  In the case of

```
(if(<= i 0)
        (write "equals zero!")  ; then 
        (reverse nL)            ; else
    )
```

you're comparing whether **i** is less than or equal to zero, and if it is, you print equals zero, and if it's not, you (non-destructively) reverse nL and discard the result.  Then you finish the function by making a call to **triangle**.  It seems like you probably want to *return* the reversed nL when i is less than or equal to zero.  Use **cond** instead, since you can have multiple body forms, as in:

```
(cond
  ((<= i 0) (write ...) (reverse nL))
  (t (triangle ...)))
```

You could also use **if** with **progn** to group the forms:

```
(if (<= i 0) 
  (progn 
    (write ...)
    (reverse nL))
  (triangle ...))
```

Your other function has the same problem. If you want to return values in those first cases, you need to use a form that actually returns them.  For instance:

```
(if (< n 1)
    (list 1)
    (if (= n 1)
        (last l)
        (bell #| ... |#)))
```

More idiomatic would be **cond**, and using **list** rather than **l**, which looks a lot like **1**:

```
(cond
  ((< n 1) (list 1))
  ((= n 1) (last list))
  (t (bell #| ... |#)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for the explanations. I eventually arrived at the code below. I realized that the if block worked something like..

(if (condition) (execute statement) (else execute this statement))

```
(defun bell(l n)
    (if (< n 2)(last l)
        (bell (triangle l (last l) 0) (- n 1))
    )
)
(defun triangle(pL nL i)
    (if(= i (list-length pL)) nL
        (triangle pL (append  nL (list (+ (nth  i pL) (nth i nL)))) (+ i 1))
    )  
)
(write (bell (list 1) 10))
```